# Asp.net Web Api - Custom AuthorizeAttribute error there is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have a custom authorize attribute that i used to to verify if a user has switched to another mobile device. In the case where a user login to a new mobile device, the previous mobile device will logout.Therefore this custom authorize attribute is to check if the user is still logged on to same mobile device every time a authorize require api endpoint is called.

In non peak period I have no error on it. However during the peak period I have around 300-400 users using the app at the same time and this error start to occur. It only happen 1-2 times a day during the peak period. Even through this error will only affect 1-2 users a day. I will like find out what did I do wrong in resulting this error that affect the user experience.

Error message,

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.ValidateConnectionForExecute(SqlCommand command)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ValidateConnectionForExecute(String method, SqlCommand command)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ValidateCommand(String method, Boolean async)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
 at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<Reader>b__c(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
 at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__6()
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
 at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.SingleOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__2[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
 at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
 at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.DbQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
 at System.Linq.Queryable.Single[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
```

my sample code

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class WebApiCustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    private const string Token = "Token";

    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        bool isAuthroized = base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
        var db = new dbContext();
        if (isAuthroized)
        {
            var tokenValue = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues(Token).First();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tokenValue))
            {
               return false;
            }
            try
            {
               var mobile = db.Mobiles.Where(m => m.token.Equals(tokenValue) && m.UserId.HasValue).AsNoTracking().Single()
               return true;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                //log error
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: It is probably not the the cause of the problem, but I would strongly recommend disposing the DbContext object: using(var db = new dbContext()) { ... your data processing code ... }

Comment: previously i was using that but it doesn't make any different to the error.